# How to debug Laravel Site show HTTP ERROR 500?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm on Laravel 5.7, and my app loading fine on my local Mac OSX.

But on my production Ubuntu Server, I kept getting 500

[image]

---

## permissions

I've already `chmod R 777 storage/ bootstrap/ vendor/`

[image]

---

## .env

I also check my .env file, everything seem to be in place proper configured.

[image]

---

## nginx

I checked in `cd /var/log/nginx/` I see nothing there.

[image]

---

## laravel

I checked `/home/forge/bheng/storage/logs` - nothing there also.

[image]

---

## composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "laravelcollective/remote": "5.7.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.3",
        "league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0",
        "htmlmin/htmlmin": "^5.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "vinkla/instagram": "^8.0",
        "php-http/message": "^1.6",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~5.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.1",
        "filp/whoops" : "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [ "database" ],

        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: If you have access to the PROD server, maybe you could check the `laravel.log` file to see what the error is.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to prod server, what is the full path of that?

Comment: Not fully sure, as not familiar with your environment, but it is in the `storage` directory.  Something like this... [APP]/storage/logs/laravel.log.

Comment: nothing there at all - empty.

Comment: Just for the record: Giving permissions to everyone (777) one the folders `storage/ bootstrap/ vendor/` is a security issue.

To which folder as doc root is your NGINX pointing?

Comment: What do you suggest the correct one for laravel would be ? `644` ? I will update now.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x bootstrap | drwxr-xr-x vendor | storage is a symlink due to my deployment setup.

Comment: Is it 600 or 644 ?

Comment: Is this running on apache or nginx? You need to check the server logs first since its a 500 error..

Comment: what is the path to check server log ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the php version is correct, to know PHP version your Apache server is using use phpinfo(),[php version check](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) but you might get a different version in php -v. if that is the issue use

```
    $ sudo a2dismod php5.6
    $ sudo a2enmod php7.1
    $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

To switch php versions and then goto bootstrap/cache folder and clear the folder.

Comment: I am not using apache. I am using nginx, your answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `laravel.log` file has only `root` lavel write permission, however it seems your webserver using `www-data` as a group and maybe a user too. You can change group and owner of `laravel.log` file.

```
chown  www-data:www-data /home/forge/bheng/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

after this it will start logging.

For file permission in Laravel 5 you can check this [How to set up File Permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Comment: I tried that command, and refresh my page, I got 500 error again.

Comment: Check the log after, see nothing there.